# writing time modified stamp to the top of a file

Tags: c, time, io, timestamp, logfile

So I'm trying to write a Time Created and a Last Modified time stamp to the top of a report file. The code seems very simple, but it will not work.
The top of the file should look like this:

```
File created: *timestamp*
Last updated: *timestamp*
```

When the file is first created both timestamps should be the same. On each successive modification of the file the second one should be updated. However, the second time stamp never seems to change. Here's the code. Note that the string returned by asctime() has a built-in new line, which I thought was counter-intuitive.

```
NewFile = 0;
//open for updating, or create
if(   (fid = fopen(FileName,"r+"))   ==    NULL){
    NewFile = 1;
    if(   (fid = fopen(FileName,"w"))    ==    NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: Could not access file\n",FileName);
        return 1;
    }
}

// Update time
time(&rawtime);
timestruct=localtime(&rawtime);

if(NewFile){
    fprintf(fid,"File created: %32s",asctime(timestruct)); //write the creation timestamp
}else{
    fgets(linebuffer,128,fid); //skip over the creation timestamp
}
printf("Last Updated: %s\n",asctime(timestruct)); //prints correct time to console
fprintf(fid,"Last Updated: %32s\n",asctime(timestruct)); //doesn't seem to have an effect on the file
//fprintf(fid,"Last Updated: %32s\n",asctime(timestruct));

fflush(fid);
fclose(fid);
return 0;
```

The odd thing is that the printf() statement prints the correct time to the console. But the equivalent fprintf() statement keeps turning out the original time. To experiment I added an extra fprintf statement which is identical to the first (commented out in the code above). This was to make sure that the fprintf() was doing anything at all. The result was three timestamps that always reflected the time of creation.

I've been working a lot of hours so my brain is pretty dead. So maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: always ONLY open the file for "w+", never for read. use stat() to determine if the file already exists and if already exists, then only update timestamp(s).  use fseek() to position in file for a write to the 'update' timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening using "w+" and switching between reading and writing needs a fseek.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {
    char linebuffer[256] = {0};
    int NewFile = 0;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *timestruct;
    FILE *fid;
    //open for updating, or create
    if(   (fid = fopen("FileName","r+"))   ==    NULL){
        NewFile = 1;
        if(   (fid = fopen("FileName","w+"))    ==    NULL){// open with w+
            fprintf(stderr,"Could not access FileName\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Update time
    time(&rawtime);
    timestruct=localtime(&rawtime);

    if(NewFile){
        fprintf(fid,"File created: %32s",asctime(timestruct)); //write the creation timestamp
    }else{
        fgets(linebuffer,128,fid); //skip over the creation timestamp
        fseek ( fid, 0, SEEK_CUR);//switch from read to write
    }
    printf("Last Updated: %s\n",asctime(timestruct));
    fprintf(fid,"Last Updated: %32s\n",asctime(timestruct));// now writing

    fclose(fid);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Added just the fseek() and it fixed it. I didn't realize that was a requirement. I don't do too much I/O in C. Thanks!